# iText .setFontSize Exception dict.not.contain.font.data

Tags: jakarta-ee, itext, acrofields, itext7

I am trying to a PDF form that data is filled via a Java EE backing bean using iText libraries.  The form was created using InDesign by layering text fields on top of a form image, then exporting it to a PDF. My problem is that the font size does not seem to exported PDF.  If the PDF is brought up in Adobe Reader, the font size does seem to apply (be it 'auto' or specific # line 8). But when manipulated with iText libs, it is ignored.  I found that I can force a size when setting the value, but now get a "FATAL:   #{njBean.testForm()}: com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: dict.not.contain.font.data" on the method call to ".setFontSize(8)" 
I cannot find anything stating how to force a default font to be used for the text field from the InDesign side.  What am I missing??

I am using iText 7.0.0; InDesign CC 11.4.0.90 .... Here is the code segments:

```
public void testForm() throws IOException, Exception {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    manipulatePdf(SRC, DEST);
}
```

...

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, Exception {
    String dow = EMPTY_STRING;  //test var
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
    boolean foundDriver1 = false;
    boolean foundDriver2 = false;


    // Use to access bundled resources
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    try ( 
            //Initialize PDF document
            InputStream input = ec.getResourceAsStream(SRC);
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(input), new PdfWriter(dest))
        ) {

        revData = loadData(..from database..);
        driverData = loadDrivers(..from database..);
        setupRecord = loadSetup(..from database..

        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
        Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getFormFields();
```

....

```
        fillField(fields, "agencyDescP1", setupRecord.getDepartment());
```

....

```
private void fillField(Map<String, PdfFormField> fields, String fieldName, String value) throws Exception {
    PdfFormField field = fields.get(fieldName);
    if (value == null)
        value = "-";
    if (field != null)
        field.setValue(value).setFontSize(8);
    else
        throw new Exception("Unable to find field on PDF: " + fieldName);
}
```

Comment: Please share a pdf sample to reproduce your issue with.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug that was already fixed. The fix will be available in the next release. See the [iText 7 form examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-differences-itext-5/forms) and look at the `cmp_` files. Those examples didn't work in iText 7.0.0, but I fixed those bugs. The examples are to be shown at JavaOne in two weeks. The new version should be released by then.

Comment: Thank you for the update and I will look forward to the next version in the next couple weeks and let you know if I am still having problems.